# Is it possible to load image in external Storage as bitmap with android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-permissions, samsung-galaxy, android-api-levels

I am developing app with my Galaxy A31 which Android OS version is 11.
My client requested to add picture for Application.

If I use ***READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE*** permission, I can easily add this feature in the app.
But Someone other developer said Google will remove entire app which have this permission until this november,
And Galaxy Store also!

And the app should display the image on ImageView with bitmap.

Can I do that on Android 13+?

In my Galaxy A31, the app skip request ***READ_MEDIA_IMAGES***!

Below is my source code. It is Java, and in *onCreate()*

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES}, 1);
        } else {
            addPictureButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                imageIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 1);

                Uri uri = imageIntent.getData();

                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                photoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                cursor.close();
            });
        }
```

And below source code is load bitmap from external storage.
I wanna know whether It cause *java.lang.SecurityException*.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: `add picture for Application.` What do you mean? Your app should create an image file? Then READ permissions are useless. Tell better what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ACTION_GET_CONTENT you do not need any permission.

That was never needed.

```
 imageView.setImageUri(uri);
```

Do away with that photo path.

For all Android versions. –

Comment: I need to add music also...

Comment: To what? And how? You can always use the uri. No need for paths. But it would be a different question. Dont come with new questions on the fly.

Comment: I just tested on my mother's Galaxy S23 which OS is Android 13. It cause NullPointerException when use cursor from Uri. You're right. Handle Uri is best way. Do not use file absolute path.